# jQuery Mobile checkbox refresh not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to change the state of my jQuery Mobile checkboxes using the following code:

```
$('#_inputcb_Q801').prop('checked', false);
```

I also found the following solution on jQuery Mobile:

```
$('#_inputcb_Q801').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
```

but it gives this error:

> Runtime-error Microsoft JScript: cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: The error message seems to be pretty indicative of the issue. Most likely the like calling the refresh is loaded before the plugin is bound to the element `$('#_inputcb_Q801').checkbox()`. Just make sure you are not calling the refresh before you initialize the plugin on the element.

Comment: I found this method worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027566/how-to-check-checkbox-dynamically-jquery-mobile#67749920

Answer (score 3):

try it.

- checkbox

  `$('.ui-checkbox input').attr('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');`
- selectbox

  `$('.ui-select select').val('').selectmenu('refresh');`

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, ill post it below it might help someone:

```
  $('#_bQ801').click(function(){
        $.mobile.changePage('#Question_09_01', 'slide', false, false);
        $('#_inputcb_Q901').attr('checked', false);
        $('#_inputcb_Q901').checkboxradio('refresh');}
```

Comment: Improvement: remove click-handler, remove $.mobile... Only the last two statements  are required.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$('#_inputcb_Q801').attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it works but it doesnt update the user view, in code it's unchecked but the user still sees the checkbox as checked.

Comment: I think it will update view too. Try it
    $('#_inputcb_Q801').change();

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it does update the underlying checkbox, but as user1652050 mentioned, it does not update the enhanced code made by jQuerymobile. You have to update it as well.