# How to check "checkbox" dynamically - jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

With HTML a checkbox is created like this:

```
<form>
   <input type="checkbox" id="category1">Category1<br>
</form>
```

With javascript we can check the checkbox like this:

```
$("#category1")[0].checked = true
```

Now I am trying to create the same page with jquery-mobile. The checkbox looks like this:

```
<form>
    <label>
        <input name="checkbox-0 " type="checkbox">Check me
    </label>
</form>
```

Why is there is no `id` here? Is the name the `id`? Should I delete the attribute name and create one with the name `id`?

How can I check this checkbox here with Javascript/jQuery?

I tried the code above, but it doesn't seem to work for this checkbox.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138898/check-if-a-jquery-mobile-checkbox-is-checked Have you gone though the proper documentations and all other questions related to this sort of topic?

Comment: I DID check the docs. I was in this page: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/checkbox/ . Theres nothing there about javascript. Just the jquery mobile part.

Comment: for JS always check [jQuery Mobile API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/#method-refresh).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to refresh it after changing its' `.prop`, using `.checkboxradio('refresh')`. This is the correct way to check checkbox/radio in jQuery Mobile.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3bjmJ/)**

```
$('.selector').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
```

Reference: [jQuery Mobile API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/#method-refresh)

Comment: Perfect answer as always Omar. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @JonhSmid Thank you and take it easy buddy :)

Comment: thankyou!  also, why?!?!

ah, per the documentation: https://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/#method-refresh

Comment: I get the error `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'` even in the linked demo page.  See my answer for how I got it working.

Comment: @SharpC wrap it in `pagecreate` event. You're calling `refresh` before the widget is initialized.

Comment: @Omar in my code this is actually while the page is displayed and after a user event.  The linked demo also fails with the same error in Chrome at the moment.

Comment: @sharpc the linked demo is old, the libraries most likely aren’t linked properly. All the demos in my answers aren’t working as I need to update each and every one. Since you’re using flip switch widget, you need to call flipswitch methods not checkboxradio.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
$('input[name="checkbox-0"]').prop("checked", true).checkboxradio('refresh'); //sets the checkbox
var isChecked =  $('input[name="checkbox-0"]').prop("checked"); //gets the status
```

Comment: if i gave an id to the checkbox would that be correct :
$(#id_name).prop("checked", true); ?

Comment: Yes, dont forget the quotes in the selector `$("#id_name").prop("checked", true);`

Comment: @JonhSmid -- Was unaware, I've updated my answer. Thx for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [jQ Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",true);
```

Comment: $("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh"); Straight there!

Answer (score 0):

With the solution from @Omar I get the error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

I actually had a [flipswitch checkbox](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/flipswitch):

```
<div class="some-checkbox-area">
    <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-lesson-complete"
           data-on-text="Complete" data-off-text="Incomplete" data-wrapper-class="custom-size-flipswitch">
</div>
```

and found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285280/how-to-change-the-jquery-mobile-flip-switch-state-from-code#32876231) was:

```
$("div.ui-page-active div.some-checkbox-area div.ui-flipswitch input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", true).flipswitch( "refresh" )
```

**Notes**

- I don't usually specify ids for page content as jQuery Mobile loads multiple `div.ui-page` content into a single HTML page for performance.   I therefore never really understood how I could use `id` if it might then occur more than once in the HTML `body` (maybe someone can clarify this).
- If I use `prop` rather than `attr` the switch goes into an infinite flipping loop!  I didn't investigate further...

Comment: flipswitch and checkbox are two different widgets. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797694/1771795