# Setting radio button without interaction and only with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I try to set a radio button in a group without directly click on the button. Aim is to open a jQuery page and depending on a stored value the related radio button should be set. I read a lot of similar articles and tried the solutions of this but no one works in my case. I created a jsfiddle to show my use case: http://jsfiddle.net/yZejX/2/ .

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-1" value="3">Test1</input>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-2" value="4">Test2</input>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-3" value="5">Test3</input>
```

JS:

```
// try to set the attribute directly
$("#radio-choice-1").attr('data-icon','radio-on');
$("#radio-choice-2").attr('data-icon','radio-off');
$("#radio-choice-3").attr('data-icon','radio-off');

// try to set via click event
$("#radio-choice-2").click();

// try to set via changing attribute and call change event to update
$("#radio-choice-2").attr('checked','checked').change();

// try to set via reset checked element and changing attribute
$("input[name='test']:checked").removeAttr('checked');
$("input[name='test'][value='3']").attr('checked',true).change();
$("input[name='test'][value='3']").attr('checked','checked').change();
```

Has somebody an idea what I did wrong and where the mistake is?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check "checkbox" dynamically - jQuery Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027566/how-to-check-checkbox-dynamically-jquery-mobile) - `$('.selector').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#radio-choice-2").attr('checked','checked');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yZejX/4/

Comment: Big thanks for your help. Now it works at the jsfiddle but not at my application. The only difference is that I call a function, which contains the code. If the radio button group is preselected (I click e.g. on the third button) and I try to change it with your code, nothing happens :-(.

Comment: can you post the code where you check _If the radio button group is preselected _?

Comment: I solved my problem (see my answer). Thank you for helping and quick resonse.

Answer (score 0):

To set the status of radio button, here is what you do in javascript

```
 radiobtn = document.getElementById("radio-choice-1");
 radiobtn.checked = true;
```

Comment: This solution works also fine for the unselected case. But I have the problem that I see at the HTML code the correct radio button as selected and the browser displays a different one :-(. I get this case when I go to the page and the correct value is selected via your solution. Now I change via click to another radio button and leave the page. Now I call the page again and the browser shows me the clicked radio button and not the one I selected via script. i hope it is not to confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can render it checked with something like this:

```
document.getElementById('radio-choice-1').checked=true;
```

Or, if you prefer to stick to jQuery:

```
$('#radio-choice-2').prop('checked','true');
```

Comment: This solution works also fine for the unselected case. But I have the problem that I see at the HTML code the correct radio button as selected and the browser displays a different one :-(. I get this case when I go to the page and the correct value is selected via your solution. Now I change via click to another radio button and leave the page. Now I call the page again and the browser shows me the clicked radio button and not the one I selected via script. I hope it is not to confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your quick response and for all solutions. Each works and is great. I solved my problem with a refresh after changing the radio button:

HTML

```
<input class="rbgroup1" type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-1" value="3" checked>Test1</input>
<br>
<input class="rbgroup1" type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-2" value="4">Test2</input>
<br>
<input class="rbgroup1" type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-3" value="5">Test3</input>
```

JS

```
$(".rbgroup1").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Now it seems that it works. I thought that changing the *checked* attribute is enough, but that was not in my case.

Have a nice day.

Greetings,
Thomas