# Jquery mobile checking checkbox dynamically is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have have checkbox from jquery mobile

```
     <form>
    <input class="checkclass"   name="d11" id="checkbox-mini-0" data-mini="true" type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-mini-0">Completed This.</label>
   </form>
         <br><br>
         <div id="checkit">check</div>
```

I am trying to check dynamically based on **name="d11"** using below js

```
$('#checkit').click(function() {
$("input[name='d11']").prop('checked', true);
    alert("hi");
});
```

here is the fiddle ..http://jsfiddle.net/w2jJs/ ..But its not working in jquery mobile.some one please guide me where i am wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027566/how-to-check-checkbox-dynamically-jquery-mobile/17027734#17027734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.checkboxradio()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/#method-refresh) for jQuery mobile

```
$('#checkit').click(function () {
    $("input[name='d11']").prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w2jJs/1/)

Comment: @Vishnu Do you mean jQuery mobile 1.4.0? Because .prop() shouldn't work either since it's added in 1.6

Comment: yea sorry jquery mobile 1.4.0