# jquery mobile - change flip switch default state

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, flip, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I'm using jQuery mobile's flip switch and by default the switches are off. I can't figure out how to set the default value to 'ON'

```
<form id="sound-switch">
        <select name="flip-3" id="snd-switch" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="true">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option value="on">On</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I read somewhere to add `value="on"` to the html but I can't get it to work. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Try `<option selceted="selected" value="on">On</option>`

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: @TusharGupta's solution worked, thanks. I'm using 1.4.0 for the record.

Comment: @rizzledon should i post it as answer ?

Comment: @TusharGupta `selected` works but `selected="selected"` doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/x2dw2/

Comment: @Omar Pls check http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fx47d/

Comment: @TusharGupta They're both working for me, could it be a browser issue? I tried FF and Safari.

Comment: @TusharGupta Yes post it as an answer

Comment: @Omar do look at my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

Added `selected="selected"` to On so that it is selected when it page loads.

By default always first option is selected

```
<option selceted="selected" value="on">On</option>
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fx47d/)</kbd>

```
<form id="sound-switch">
    <select name="flip-3" id="snd-switch" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="true">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="on">On</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

---

Check here http://validator.w3.org/check

`SELECTED` is not a member of a group specified for any attribute

using `SELECTED` will work but not pass w3 says invalid :)

use `selected="selected"`

Comment: there is a typo _selceted=_ in your first comment, i copied it as is. yup, `selected="selected"` does work. +1

Answer (score 10):

Use `.val()` to set the Flipswitch's *value* and then *re-enhance* it [`.flipswitch("refresh")`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/flipswitch/#method-refresh).

```
$("#snd-switch").val("on").flipswitch("refresh");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7fCYA/)**

Comment: Do you think it's wiser using this method over setting it in the html?

Comment: @rizzledon HTML is definitely wiser. Use this when you want to set it dynamically.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why setting value on the select wasn't working. Was missing the flipswitch call.

Comment: finally the answer I was searching for a long time - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Default value would be the first option for some reasons.
You should go the option of 'ON' first, or just set as 'SELECTED' as like the following;

```
<form id="sound-switch">
    <select name="flip-3" id="snd-switch" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="true">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option selected value="on">On</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine +1.