# JQuery css label prevents Select All from working

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
    <title>collapsible demo</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">  
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#cb-mlb-all").change(function(){
            $(".cb-mlb").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
        });                
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<form>
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="ui-input-form">
                <ul class="chk-container">
                <label for="cb-mlb-all">Select all<input type="checkbox" value="" id="cb-mlb-all" /></label>
                <label for="cb-mlb-ar">Arizona<input class="cb-mlb" type="checkbox" value="" id="cb-mlb-ar" /></label>
                <label for="cb-mlb-at">Atlanta<input class="cb-mlb" type="checkbox" value="" id="cb-mlb-at" /></label>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Adding the Label tags around the checkboxes makes the output look better, however now the Select All checkbox does not cause the other checkboxs to get checked / unchecked like they did without the Label tags.

Comment: If I comment out the line: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"> , then the Select All works again but the output does not look as good.

Comment: Actually your code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/Shedal/gqm6n0fn/1/

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Yes since you don't have the jquery-mobile pack in your fiddle. Just as Jack commented.

Comment: @Hydrospanners got it

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as your solution @Jack.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the states of the radio buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cb-mlb-all").change(function() {
        $('.cb-mlb').prop('checked',$(this).is(':checked')).checkboxradio('refresh')
    });
});
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/#method-refresh)

Comment: Found a duplicate [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027566/how-to-check-checkbox-dynamically-jquery-mobile)

Comment: may be you can add this specific link to your answer https://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/#method-refresh

Comment: @Reddy Thanks, i did.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was working fine and your checkbox were getting checked and uncheked properly. Only issue was the tick mark is toggled by `setting the class of the label` which is above the checkbox to `ui-checkbox-off` and `ui-checkbox-on` Here  is my fix to it..

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/2t6e1nm5/2/)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#cb-mlb-all").change(function(){
      $(".cb-mlb").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));

      var $labels = $(".cb-mlb").parent().find('label');
        if($(this).prop('checked')){ // toggle the label classes           
          $labels.removeClass('ui-checkbox-off');    
          $labels.addClass('ui-checkbox-on');       
        }
        else{
         $labels.removeClass('ui-checkbox-on');
         $labels.addClass('ui-checkbox-off');    
        }            
    });                
});
```

Comment: whoever it is ...What is the problem? why downvote, check the fiddle and care to comment.

Comment: I upvoted you. I guess the downvoter's problem was that you didn't include code in your answer originally.

Comment: This isn't using the built-in & already included functionality of JQuery Mobile. Perhaps that's why?

Comment: oh my bad, ok thanks for the info @DmytroShevchenko , I was trying to include the snippet but for some reason its not working in snippet, So posted the Jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind help!!! I tried Reddy's block of code above and now it works. I've been trying for weeks to fix this. Really appreciate everyone's help!!!! Jack

Comment: @Jack glad to know you fixed the issue, if this solution resolved your issue then you can mark it as answer so that it might help future audience

Comment: Thanks to Dmytro and Hydrospanners as well. I haven't used Stacktrace actively. Not sure how to upvote. I clicked the up arrow on Reddy's answer it went up to 2 then back down to 1 within a second. Not sure if it worked..

Comment: If you click it once, its a upvote, if you click again the vote is removed. Also to mark it answer there is a check mark icon which you need to select.